# JSR223 cant catch chromeOptions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jsr223

Can someone help with chrome Options and capabilities in JSR223 Sampler in Jmeter?
This code works properly in eclipce, but seems like JSR Sampler doesn't see options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); 
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/AntonK/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default"); 
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999/wd/hub"), dc);
```

chrome started in window instead maximased
and with temp profile instead specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [selenium-chrome-driver-2.52.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.52.0) (comes with JMeter [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin) and [selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-standalone/2.53.0)

[image: JMeter WebDriver Chrome Options]

1. Make sure to add necessary [imports](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html), to wit:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
   import java.net.URL;
   ```
2. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries
3. Make sure you choose [`groovy`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) in the Language dropdown, don't be confused with `java` language option which is not real Java but [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) interpreter

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think it because i'm using  selenium-server-standalone-3.x.x

Comment: How can I use this for all the selenium/webdriver samples in a thread group as I have to run the test plan in chrome headless mode and after adding the explicit wait of 150 seconds it won't work and gives me an error `expected conditions wait for 150 seconds`.